# How to configure red/green output for ZSH Prompt Mac 11.3.1 BigSur 2021

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, terminal, zsh

I have just got a new Mac and I am trying to customise the shell so that I can set colors.
I do not want to be using OhMyZsh and all that extra jazz as I don't need it yet.

What I want is the prompt to start out as white, then if the command is a success, including ls commands etc, I want all the output to be green,
If there is a bad command or incorrect syntax or if something fails, I want the output to be red.

For my PS1 Prompt, all I want displayed is the directory path which I have managed to do as can be seen below:

```
PS1='%F{255}%d -> %f'
```

How can I modify the above so all positive output is green and all negative output including bad commands, syntax errors etc is red,
If this is even possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print `$PS1` the way it appears in your prompt, you need to use

```sh
print -P -- "$PS1"
```

> I don't understand how to add colors or change the prompt to dynamic values.

Read the [Zsh manual on prompt escape sequences](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html).

> How can I have everything coloured green when the command was successful & red, when it was not?

```sh
PS1='%(?,%F{green},%F{red})%n@%, %1~ %#%f '
```

Comment: I can print PS1, It was about the escape sequences, How can I have everything coloured green when the command was successful & red, when it was not?

Comment: @ptmp_727 Sorry, that wasn't clear from your original post. Can you please update your post to include that question? Then I will update my answer, too.

Comment: @ptmp_727 OK, I already updated my answer, but please do still update your question. :)

Comment: Its my bad for not being very clear, Im going to post the question properly in a bit

Comment: Done, Question updated, Your answer works great, but it only updates the prompt color, not the color of the output, is this possible?

Comment: Which output? If the command that returned non-zero? No, not possible, because by the time you receive the exit status of a command, it will have already terminated. Any output it produces will have to happened before that. The only place you can modify this is in the command itself.

Comment: @ptmp_727 : If you really want to (I wouldn't), you could writre a wrapper around your command, which runs the command, collects its exit code, its stdout and stderr, and then prints this output prefixed by the necessary escape codes for turning on the desired colour. This approach would let you even distinguish between, say, exit code 1 and 2.